# How to use WebGL on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I remember Google Maps often asking me if I wanted to use 'web gl'. When I said yes, it reloaded, and the web gl version had better zooming in and out. Today, I can't find the option for Web GL. Where is it? Did Google remove it?

https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&t=h

Comment: AFAIK some browsers do not support Web GL. So, if you are using another browser, this option may be unavailable. Just guessing...

Comment: Could be. My browser is Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.52 beta-m